# How to position 400 x 400px popup div relative to click, keeping in screen view

Tags: jquery, click, screen, position

Preferably with jQuery since it's so much easier to understand.

The following works great for horizontal.  The issue is vertical can be cut off on top requiring the user to scroll up to see the entire popup.

```
function pop_IT(X,event){
    dist_to_right_edge = $('body').innerWidth()-(x-$.scrollbarWidth());
    dist_to_bottom = $(window).height()-y;
    X=$('#'+X).get(0);
    X.style.left = 5+x+"px";
    X.style.top = 5+y+"px";
    if(dist_to_right_edge < (X.offsetWidth+5)){X.style.left = x - X.offsetWidth-5+"px";}
    if(dist_to_bottom < (X.offsetHeight+5)){X.style.top = y - X.offsetHeight-5+"px";}
    }
```

Then I load something like

```
$('#object').load('../whatever.php',function(event){pop_IT('object',event);});
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be pretty simple

```
<div class="popup" > test</div>

.popup
{
 position:absolute;
 width:400px;
 height:400px;
}
```

jquery:

get offset of the parent element , i mean click element

```
$("#yourclickdiv").click(function (e) {
  var offset = $(this).offset();
  $(#popup).css('left',offset.left);    
  $(#popup).css('top',offset.top);
});
```

This should do it.

Comment: @trail...you can add some pixel to left and top

Comment: but if he does it near the edge of the screen he wont be able to see all of it, he wants it to calculate if it's on the screen and if it's not, to re-position it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$(document).click(function (e) {

  var x = e.clientX,
  y = e.clientY,
  width = $(window).width(),
  height = $(window).height();

  if( x > width - 400 ) x -= 400;
  if( y > height - 400 ) y -= 400;

  $('#popup').css({'top':y,'left':x});

});
```