# how to create control for real time Edit in jquery + asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i have one `<li>` element where i put Item1 and value and Edit button, when i click on Editbutton the small popup open with slider and numeric up and down

problem is , i am wondering when i change the slider i want to change `<li>` background color and from numeric up and down i want to change values in `<li>` elements

for example here, if i change slider value up , i want to make `<li>` background color something else and if i click numeric up i want 26  in `<li>` element

it should be real time, means u click on up value should be 26 in li, No after close popup or something else

[image: +]

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried something? Not clear where you have a problem.

Comment: I just made list of <li> but , i do not know how to open popupmodal to edit the things

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/). Here you can also find a slider control. Also, if you want to get something like on your picture, take a look at an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825763/how-to-position-400-x-400px-popup-div-relative-to-click-keeping-in-screen-view).