# cant position pop up div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

looking for advice from [How to position 400 x 400px popup div relative to click, keeping in screen view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825763/how-to-position-400-x-400px-popup-div-relative-to-click-keeping-in-screen-view)

I am loading a jquery pop up div. trouble being it is displaying in the middle of the screen I cant get it top display at the top of the screen...

```
<script>
        $(function () {
                        $("#saveDialogSingleFeature").dialog();
                    });
</script>

    <div style="display: none;">
                <div id="saveDialogSingleFeature" title="Save Complete">
                    <p>
                        You have successfully saved 1 feature.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

As I said div opens fine I just need to change the position it is displayed at. I have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#saveDialogSingleFeature').css({ 'top': 10, 'left': 10 });
    </script>
```

and adding a class .saveFeaturePopUp to the div...

```
<style type="text/css">
         .saveFeaturePopUp
         {
            position: {my: "top", at: "bottom", of: $("header")};
         }
     </style>
```

but to no avail. please advise

Answer (score 2):

You should just need to set Position:absolute in your css.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#saveDialogSingleFeature').css({position: 'absolute', 'top': 10, 'left': 10 });
    </script>
```

Comment: hi thanks for reply....this moves the contents of the DIV, but not the container...as in....the outer layer of the jquery popup still appears in the middle of the screen with the header...'Save complete'....but the text You have successfully saved 1 feature is positioned to what I set it to...top 10, left 10....also the white background of the div is now transparent

Comment: You should also be able to just change the option to something like: position: { my: "left top", at: "left+10 top+10"}